# Unit testing : nice to have feature question

Tags: xml, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am testing a web service using VS2008 built in Unit testing , which btw isn't 1/2 bad. 
the webservice returns a complex datatype...

What I would like to do now... is add code to serialize the return object, then display it as xml using internet explorer or ff (both of which show nicely formatted XML).

What I really want to know is...

Do I need to save that object as serialized xml to file system, then perform a process.start...

or...

is there an easier way to show the contents in the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you have to save it as an xml file and then start the browser.

Comment: I know its a bit of work, but it really gives the test process that much more polish. And project managers will love you :)